# Menu vertical lateral fixo com rolagem limitada

Tags: javascript, css, menu, sidebar

Como faço um menu que nem o do Wordpress que é vertical, fixo e tem uma rolagem própria que é limitada até as suas extremidades:

[image: gif mostrando o menu]var last_scroll;

No wordpress a div do elemento recebe um "position:fixed" ao chegar no fim e no começo do menu para parar de interagir com a rolagem, e ao rolar ele defide "position:absolute" e "top:NumeroQueNaoConsigoFazer".

Eu estava tentando fazer com javascript mas está impossível:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    element = $('#sidebar_main');
    p_current = $(this).scrollTop();
    h_nav = element.height();
    h_screen = $(window).height();

    if(h_nav > h_screen){//se maior que a tela
        h = (h_nav - h_screen)+40;

        if(p_current > last_scroll){//se desce
            if(p_current>=h){//se já chegou no fim
                element.css({
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'bottom': '0',
                    'top': 'auto'
                });
            }else{
                if(element.css('top') == 'auto'){
                    element.css('top', 0);
                }
                element.css({
                    'top': '+=1px',
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'bottom': 'auto'
                });
            }
        }else{//se sobe

            if(p_current<=0){//se já chegou no começo
                element.css({
                    'top': '0',
                    'bottom': 'auto'
                });
            }else{
                //if(element.offset().top <= h || element.css('top') == 'auto'){


                    if(element.css('top') == 'auto'){
                        element.css('top', element.offset().top);
                    }
                    element.css({
                        'top': '-=1px',
                        'position': 'absolute',
                        'bottom': 'auto'
                    });
                }
            //}
        }

        last_scroll = p_current;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Possível solução!

Adicionei um elemento `nav` e nele apliquei algumas diretivas css

- `float: left;` // Flutuar elemento na esquerda
- `height:  100vh;` // **vh** é uma unidade de medida! Nela você pega 100% do *viewport* (tamanho da tela do dispositivo)
- `overflow: auto;` // Adiciona a barra de rolagem caso os itens internos ultrapassem a altura limite

```css
#nav-lateral {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  height:  100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

#nav-lateral a, ul >li {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  /*top left bottom right*/
}

#nav-lateral ul {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#nav-lateral ul li{
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-lateral">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
    <li>Menu 5</li>
    <li>Menu 6</li>
    <li>Menu 7</li>
    <li>Menu 8</li>
    <li>Menu 9</li>
    <li>Menu 10</li>
    <li>Menu 11</li>
    <li>Menu 12</li>

  </ul>
</nav>

<div>Resto do conteúdo</div>
```

**Obs.:** Perceba que quando clicar em `Executar trecho de código` vai criar a barra de rolagem agora click em `Página toda` a barra some!

Answer (score -1):

Esse site tem um tutorial, eles usam um plugin JS, basta você olhar o código e implementar no seu...
`http://www.criarsites.me/tutoriais/menu-scroll-fixo-jquery/`

Mas é bem simples, basta chamar o plugin do jQuery no `head` e implementar pequenas mudanças no CSS.

`<script src="js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Evite links como resposta!

Comment: Ok ! De qualquer forma, é uma dica a ser levada em consideração...

Comment: Ainda continua na mesma. Sua resposta não responde a pergunta, está direcionando a solução "real" para o link de qualquer jeito. Para que a resposta fique independente do link, você pode adicionar um exemplo de solução em código no corpo da resposta, assim, o link apenas servirá de referencia, ao inves de ser a resposta